# Asymptotic lower bound for the prime counting function, $\pi(x)?$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds

Consider a function that attempts to count primes up to a given $x$:$$\varphi(x)=\int_2^x \frac{1}{\log(t)}e^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}}~dt$$

> Is $\varphi(x)$ an asymptotic lower bound to the prime counting function, $\pi(x)?$

If you take away the square root on the $t$ the function does only slightly better than $Li(x)$ and I'm interested in a lower bound that is also asymptotic.

Just to provide some numerical results, $\varphi(10^9)$ is less than $\pi(10^9)$ by approximately $1,750$ which is approximately the difference between $Li(x)$ and $\pi(x).$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\phi(x) = \int_2^x \frac1{\log t}e^{-1/\sqrt t}\,dt &= \int_2^x \frac1{\log t} \bigg( 1 - \frac1{\sqrt t} + O\bigg( \frac1t \bigg) \bigg)\,dt \\
&= \mathop{\rm li}(x) - \int_2^x \frac1{\sqrt t\log t}\,dt + O(\log\log x).
\end{align*}
The integral has order of magnitude $\sqrt x/\log x$. Since $\pi(x)-\mathop{\rm li}(x)$ can be as small as $-\sqrt x\log\log\log x/\log x$ by Littlewood's result, this function $\phi(x)$ is not eventually a lower bound for $\pi(x)$.

Comment: Hi, I haven't looked into Littlewood's results, but according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#The_Riemann_hypothesis

this is equivalent to the Riemann hypothesis. 
$${\displaystyle |\pi (x)-\operatorname {li} (x)|<{\frac {\sqrt {x}}{8\pi }}\,\log {x},\qquad {\text{for all }}x\geq 2657.}$$

now sqrt(x) log log log x  / log x 
is asymtotically way larger than sqrt(x)/log(x)

Can you explain why both can still be true to me?

Comment: Note that the formula from Wikipedia has $\log x$ in the numerator, not the denominator. So they are consistent with each other.

Comment: ohhh
yeah i missed that, thx.